# Not able to update password into mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql

So,i am trying to change the password in the table users,for that i am using the following php code,but it is not getting updated.

```
<?php
session_start();
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="bloodbank"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="users"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// username ,password and newpassword sent from form 
$username=$_POST['username']; 
$password=$_POST['password']; 
$newpassword=$_POST['newpassword']; 
$sql="UPDATE $tbl_name SET password='$newpassword' WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";

?>
```

Then i tried to use this code,although i am getting "Updated Successfully",in reality it is not getting updated in the database,can anyone please tell me where error is.

```
<?php
session_start();
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="bloodbank"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="users"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// username,password and newpassword sent from form 
$username=$_POST['username']; 
$password=$_POST['password']; 
$newpassword=$_POST['newpassword'];
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count==1)
{
$mysql="UPDATE $tbl_name SET password='$newpassword'";
echo "Updated Successfully";
}
else
{
echo "Wrong password or Username";
}
?>
```

Comment: Well, that's because you're not executing the query..

Comment: can you please tell me how to do it.

Comment: where is the execution of the query?

Comment: mysql_query($mysql); :P

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: If you are going to [store passwords, do it securely](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet) — don't store them in plain text.

Comment: This appears to be exactly the same problem (storing a query in a variable and not passing it to the database) as you asked about in your last question: **Duplicate**: [unable to insert data into mysql using php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16850564/unable-to-insert-data-into-mysql-using-php)

Comment: where is WHERE in your update query?

Comment: @Edwin Lambregts thank you very much,it worked.

Comment: without WHERE condition in update, you will update field "password" in every row of your table...

Comment: @manju please read the other answers here carefully as they noticed SQL/XSS/password vulnerability. :)

Comment: very bad, i see a lot of SQL injections sir manju. please consider all comments above me :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In your first code you never execute the mysql query. The second code simply makes an useless sql query.
Try:

```
<?php
session_start();
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="bloodbank"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="users"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// username ,password and newpassword sent from form 
$username=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']); 
$password=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']); 
$newpassword=mysql_real_escape_string ($_POST['newpassword']); 
$sql="UPDATE $tbl_name SET password='$newpassword' WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
?>
```

Comment: @manju make sure that you really take into account everything Patashu posted if you are planning on using this on a publicly available website. It's really important!

Answer (score 5):

In this code

```
if($count==1)
{
$mysql="UPDATE $tbl_name SET password='$newpassword'";
echo "Updated Successfully";
}
```

there are the following problems:

1) is that you do nothing with the SQL you just constructed - you forgot to run a query using it.

2) is that you do not hash the password with a salt - storing passwords in plaintext in your database is SUPER SUPER bad, the first time anyone else gets your database by any means every single one of your users' passwords is on the internet, and now their bank accounts and emails are at risk. Don't think it won't happen, all it takes is one mistake or one thing you've overlooked, and a high proportion of people use one password for everything, so criminals LOVE it when username/password databases are leaked onto the internet. Read http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/php/php.html#bcrypt

3) is that the update statement, as written, will set EVERY SINGLE ROW's password to the value in $newpassword - you forgot to use a WHERE clause.

4) is that this code is vulnerable to SQL injection, meaning that if a hacker submits SQL code instead of a password the SQL code will be run. One solution is using prepared statements instead. See [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Thank you,i am new to this subject,will do what you showed.

Answer (score 2):

**Change:**

```
$sql="UPDATE $tbl_name SET password='$newpassword' WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";

if($count==1)
{
$mysql="UPDATE $tbl_name SET password='$newpassword'";
echo "Updated Successfully";
}
```

**To:**

```
$sql="UPDATE $tbl_name SET password='$newpassword' WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

if($count==1)
{
$mysql="UPDATE $tbl_name SET password='$newpassword'";
$result2=mysql_query($mysql);
echo "Updated Successfully";
}
```

The reason it didn't update is because the `$sql` query wasn't executing.

Comment: No problem. If this worked for you, don't forget to mask as the correct answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need WHERE condition in you UPDATE statement:

```
mysql="UPDATE $tbl_name SET password='$newpassword' WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
```

And also to execute query

```
$result2=mysql_query($mysql);
```

Regards.

Comment: old password should also be checked, because otherwise all ppl could change password for certain user.

Comment: You're right Bojane :)